# Firebase with fragments in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to implement Firebase authorization/registration in Kotlin using Fragments, but something is wrong with this keyword on OnCompleteListener. Here is my code:

```
   private fun registerUser() {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        emailRegistration.text.toString(),
        passwordRegistration.text.toString()
    ).addOnCompleteListener(this, OnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val transaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            val dashboardFragment = DashboardFragment()
            transaction?.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, dashboardFragment, "DashboardFragment")
            transaction?.commit()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean through "something is wrong with this keyword on OnCompleteListener"?

Comment: It causes the following error: \RegisterFragment.kt: (49, 11): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public final fun addOnCompleteListener(p0: (Runnable!) -> Unit, p1: (Task<AuthResult!>) -> Unit): Task<AuthResult!> defined in com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
public final fun addOnCompleteListener(p0: Activity, p1: (Task<AuthResult!>) -> Unit): Task<AuthResult!> defined in com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
public open fun addOnCompleteListener(p0: Activity, p1: OnCompleteListener<AuthResult!>): Task<AuthResult!> this code worked in activities

Comment: I fixed it, it did not need this or context